# How to split a string on another string with space characters?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm having troubles with splitting a String with another String that has space characters in.

Example:

"Team 1 vs Team 2"

I would like to split on " vs " (note the blank spaces before and after the vs).

I tried "\\svs\\s", " vs ", "\\s vs \\s" but it does not work.

Also, it might be useful to note that I'm getting the String from a .txt file.

Comment: "it does not work." [The first one does (see ideone demo)](http://ideone.com/n4yoWz). In what way does it not work?

Comment: Why not split using the word "vs"? That way you will receive Team 1 and Team 2

Comment: After String[] teams = str.split("\\svs\\s") it returns me an array of length 1.

Comment: Erick, that is leading my whole program to go nuts, for I need to compare the names, so if I just use vs, I`ll have two names for a team: "Team 1_" and "_Team 1".

Comment: `System.out.println("Team 1 vs Team 2".split("\\svs\\s").length);` this is printing 2. Double check your `str` value.

Comment: I've been trying to .trim() the string afterwards and it is not working as well. Let me check the text formatting, for there may lie the problem.

Comment: It seems the problem was with the space type that was in the file. \\s is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use this code

```
String str = "Team 1 vs Team 2";
String[] splits = str.split("vs");
```

Also, you could use Apache Commons using the `StringUtils` class as it offers many ways to split strings as per your requirement. It is well tested and we use Apache Commons split in our project widely as well.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: See the above answer on Erick.

Answer (score -1):

If you use regex, you can split and trim the result. Removing any white space before "Team 2".

```
String str = "Team 1 vs Team 2";
String[] splits = str.split("\\s*vs\\s*");
```

Your result will be:

```
Team 1
Team 2
```